# Gender Validation in Multiple Rails Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-modeling

Hey all -- this question is specifically about a `gender` validation, but I'm interested in hearing how you've all handled similar situations with much larger collections (Country selection, for example.)

I'm working on a system that lets athletes register for various events, and am currently working on a good gender validation. My question is, what's the best, most DRY way to run the same validation on many different models?

Let's say I want to validate the gender property of `Event` and `User`. I can create a helper for `validates_each` that checks values for inclusion in the very short array of ["male", "female"] before updating the `gender` attribute. But what if I want to access this same gender array in a `form_for` block, say, as an input to `collection_select`?

I have it working for one model -- I declare a `GENDERS` constant in `Event`, and have a short class method

```
def self.genders
    GENDERS
end
```

for access by forms. But where should I store the array if multiple models need access?

EDIT: One idea would be to use a class method in the application controller. Any thoughts on how appropriate this approach is would be great.

Comment: why not make Gender an entity in your design? it's a bit overkill but it probably fits in better than a hard-coded array, however short. That way it works just like any other model and can access it in collection_select without further hoops.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's my solution.  I like to go with the standard plugin-style libraries.  I'd put this in lib/acts_as_gendered:

```
module ActsAsGendered
  GENDERS = ['male', 'female']

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ActsAsGenderedMethods)
  end

  module ActsAsGenderedMethods
    def acts_as_gendered
      extend ClassMethods
      include InstanceMethods

      validates_inclusion_of :gender, :in => GENDERS
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def is_gendered?
      true
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def is_male
      gender = 'male'
    end

    def is_female
      gender = 'female'
    end

    def is_male?
      gender == 'male'
    end

    def is_female?
      gender == 'female'
    end
  end
end
```

Yeah, it might be overkill for simple genders, but you can see where all the pieces go - the GENDERS constant, the `acts_as_gendered` ActiveRecord hook, which then includes the class and instance methods and the validation.

Then, in config/initializers/gender.rb:

```
require 'acts_as_gendered'
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActsAsGendered)
```

Then, for the grand finale, the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_gendered
end
```

This pattern may seem overly complicated, but that's how most libraries end up eventually :)

**UPDATE:** To answer your comment, this is how I'd modify the acts_as_gendered method to make validations optional on a per-model basis:

```
def acts_as_gendered options={}
  config = {:allow_nil => false}
  config.merge(options) if options.is_a?(Hash)

  extend ClassMethods
  include InstanceMethods

  if config[:allow_nil]
    validates_inclusion_of :gender, :in => (GENDERS + nil)
  else
    validates_inclusion_of :gender, :in => GENDERS
  end
end
```

Now you can call it in the User model like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_gendered :allow_nil => true
end
```

I could have made it a simple parameter you pass in, but I like the clarity of passing in a hash.  And it sets you up for adding other options down the road.

Comment: awesome, I'll take it. This is a great pattern; sure, maybe complicated for genders, but answers my question about how to handle these validations for larger sets. Thanks!

Comment: Jaime, how do you recommend handling a situation where one model might allow_nil (User), while another (Event) doesn't? Do constants make more sense, if I'll need that level of control?

Comment: Hey Sam - I updated my answer with a variation that does what you asked about.  As you can see, it's a pretty versatile setup. I can't claim to have invented it, of course - I learned it from peepcode.com.  Check them out, if you haven't already!

Comment: So does this mean Gender is to stored in the DB as a string?

Comment: Yes, it does. Is this completely normalized? No, but doing so would require a much more complicated plugin that generates a couple of migrations, and probably a gender model. It also introduces extra joins into your queries. It would also result in extra queries unless the user properly included the gender model into their existing queries. It's not worth it for a trivial case like this, especially when the plugin itself is ensuring your data integrity.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right idea by storing it in a constant. The only thing I would do differently is put it in an initializer file so that it's not tied to any particular model like it is in your example. If you're worried about potential name collisions at the top level, you could put it in a module in the lib directory and include the module only in the places you intend to use it.

Comment: Awesome, +1. I'm going with the other answer, as that pattern keeps me from duplicating my self.genders class method, but this is great too.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with putting this in a constant.  I'd also put the strings themselves in constants because (1) they can change, and (2) when used in a conditional, the system will catch if you mistype them.  E.g., in your environment.rb:

```
MALE    = 'male'
FEMALE  = 'female'
GENDERS = [MALE, FEMALE]
```

And then in your code, you only ever refer to these constants, e.g.:

```
def male?
  return gender == MALE
end
```

Comment: Why not just use symbols? `GENDERS = [:male, :female]`

Comment: Yes, we could do that. But I like to use actual strings for constants like these when I might want to display a string to the user. E.g., MALE.titleize or FEMALE.pluralize.

Answer (score -1):

I would write a custom validation plugin (say, `validates_gender`). Then you would call:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates_gender :gender
end
```

Grab a copy of my [validates_as_email](https://github.com/paulschreiber/validates_as_email) plugin and use that, replacing `value =~ EMAIL_ADDRESS_RE` with your own logic.

Comment: I can write the validator -- but if I do, is there any easy way to access the array I use later on, in forms? I know the whole question is silly for gender, but it'd be important for validation on larger collections among multiple models.

Comment: Yes. You can define the contant in the validator (like I do with EMAIL_ADDRESS_RE) and then use ActiveRecord::Validations::ClassMethods::EMAIL_ADDRESS_RE elsewhere in your code.

Comment: This helps with the validation part, but not with creating a collection to use in a select box.

Comment: @Beerlington, you're wrong. He can create a constant in the validator, and access it from his ERB: <%= f.select :gender, ActiveRecord::Validations::ClassMethods::GENDER_LIST %>. I'd define a local constant to save on typing.

Comment: He could, but I was just replying to your answer, which didn't mention this. It also seems a little strange to add an application specific constant to an ActiveRecord validation class method.

Comment: well, you could create a module, and include the module in the validator as a mixin, and just reference Gender::GENDER_LIST.